# How do I set a default choice in jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

quite frustrating I can't find an example of this. How do I set the default choice?

```groovy
parameters {
    choice(
        defaultValue: 'bbb',
        name: 'param1',
        choices: 'aaa\nbbb\nccc',
        description: 'lkdsjflksjlsjdf'
    )
}
```

defaultValue is not valid here. I want the choice to be optional and a default value to be set if the pipeline is run non-manually (via a commit).

Comment: Is the default value set if the pipeline is run via a commit?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You can't specify a default value in the option. According to the documentation for the `choice` input, the first option will be the default.

> The potential choices, one per line. The value on the first line will be the default.

You can see this in the [documentation source](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/c32b6d807a5647df8b5347c8acc1b42024b597bf/war/src/main/webapp/help/parameter/choice-choices.html#L2), and also how it is invoked in the [source code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/c32b6d807a5647df8b5347c8acc1b42024b597bf/core/src/main/java/hudson/model/ChoiceParameterDefinition.java#L75).

```java
return new StringParameterValue(
  getName(), 
  defaultValue == null ? choices.get(0) : defaultValue, getDescription()
);
```

Comment: interesting so if its triggered non-interactively will param.param1 be the first choice or will it be null?

Comment: @red888 my understanding is first value for both scripted and declarative. I haven't tested out this answer yet, but I do remember being affected by [JENKINS-35698 - _Initial run of parameterized pipeline build should return properties default value_](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-35698).

Comment: Thanks, the docs are not clear about why there is no integer parameter type for example, is that on the cards, to make parameters be feature-complete?

Comment: @ConradB I don't work on much of Jenkins OSS stuff, so I couldn't be the one to tell you. I haven't been working in Jenkins for some time, so I'm not sure if things have changed.

Comment: The source code you link to seems to conflict with what you're saying... line 48 of the same file you link to shows that the constructor takes in a `defaultValue` argument, and even the snippet you show includes the `defaultValue`. The code only shows that it'll behave as you say if `defaultValue` is `null`.

Answer (score 8):

As stated by mkobit it doesn't seem possible with the `defaultValue` parameter, instead I reordered the list of choices based on the previous pick

```groovy
defaultChoices = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
choices = createChoicesWithPreviousChoice(defaultChoices, "${params.CHOICE}")

properties([
    parameters([
        choice(name: "CHOICE", choices: choices.join("\n"))
    ])   
])


node {
    stage('stuff') {
        sh("echo ${params.CHOICE}")
    }
}

List createChoicesWithPreviousChoice(List defaultChoices, String previousChoice) {
    if (previousChoice == null) {
       return defaultChoices
    }
    choices = defaultChoices.minus(previousChoice)
    choices.add(0, previousChoice)
    return choices
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using `extendedChoice` parameter of type `PT_RADIO`. It supports setting default values.

You'd have to install this [plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/extended-choice-parameter-plugin)

```
extendedChoice description: '', multiSelectDelimiter: ',', name: 'PROJ_NAME',
                quoteValue: false, saveJSONParameterToFile: false, type: 'PT_RADIO',
                value: 'a,b', visibleItemCount: 2, defaultValue: 'a'
```

It looks like below:

[image]

Comment: You should add this is a non-native plugin which looks semi-stale? Got some old PRs and hasn't been updated in 6 months https://github.com/jenkinsci/extended-choice-parameter-plugin/pulls

Answer (score 0):

I use this solution for some years now. It's similar to the one from @chris-tompkinson, but maybe with a twist. The idea is to move the choice value selected in current build to the beginning of the choice values list, thus being offered at next build as new "default value".

```js
import groovy.transform.Field

@Field
List<String> TARGET_SYS_VALUES = ['ci', 'dev', 'test', 'staging']

pipeline {
    agent { label any }

    parameters {
        choice(name: 'TARGET_SYS',
                choices: (params.TARGET_SYS ? [params.TARGET_SYS] : []) +
                             (TARGET_SYS_VALUES - 
                                 (params.TARGET_SYS ? [params.TARGET_SYS] : [])),
                description: 'Some fictive target systems')
    }
...
}
```